# Rounding a float in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a floating point number in JavaScript, like 42.563134634634. I want to display it as a string "42.56", with exactly two decimal places. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `toFixed` method:

```
var num = 42.563134634634;
alert(num.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Wow, I've never even heard of that method before. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
var num = 42.563134634634;
var res = num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function roundNumber(number, decimals) { // Arguments: number to round, number of decimal places
    var newnumber = new Number(number+'').toFixed(parseInt(decimals));
    return newnumber;
}
```

Comment: If number needs to be converted, better to see that conversion does not error. If number type is assumed, then conversion seems pointless. `parseInt(decmials)` is redundant since the first step in the *toFixed* algorithm is to call *toInteger(arg)* (ECMA-262 15.7.4.5).

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this ?
http://forums.devarticles.com/javascript-development-22/javascript-to-round-to-2-decimal-places-36190.html

Answer (score 0):

```
function roundNumber(num, dec) {
    var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
    return result;
}
```