# Why this function increase wrong decimal values?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Floating-Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)
>   [Rounding a float in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621802/rounding-a-float-in-javascript)

Why this function  increase  wrong decimal values? I want to show only one decimal.

```
var valueElement = $('#valueTempe');
function incrementValue(e){
    if(valueElement.text() < 6){
        valueElement.text(Math.max(parseFloat(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment)); 
    }

    return false;
}
$('#plus').bind('click', {increment: 0.1}, incrementValue);     
$('#minus').bind('click', {increment: -0.1}, incrementValue);
```

jsFiddle: [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/2dMQ8/)

Comment: Why do you use `Math.max()` with a single argument only? And what do you mean by *wrong decimal values*?

Comment: I assume you are looking for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/588053/218196.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .toFixed(1) as below

```
var valueElement = $('#valueTempe');
function incrementValue(e){
    if(valueElement.text() < 6){
        valueElement.text(Math.max(parseFloat(valueElement.text()) + e.data.increment).toFixed(1)); 
    }
    if(valueElement.text() == 6){
        valueElement.text(Math.max(parseFloat(valueElement.text()) -1).toFixed(1));
    }
    return false;
}


$('#plus').bind('click', {increment: 0.1}, incrementValue);     
$('#minus').bind('click', {increment: -0.1}, incrementValue);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MuhammadHani/CtbBz/)

Comment: Thnaks @MuhammadHani. How limit the max and min values? (Although not be the principal question)

Answer (score 3):

In the same way `1/3` cannot be exactly represented in decimal, `0.1` cannot be exactly represented in binary, and Javascript numbers are binary floating point values.

In Javascript `0.2 + 0.1` returns `0.30000000000000004`.
Try it in the browser console.

In effect, 53 bits are available to store the mantissa in a Javascript 64-bit floating point value, and the decimal value `0.1` in binary rounded to a precision of 53 bits is
`0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010`
which when converted back to decimal is exactly
`0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

We can show this using using `toFixed` with Firefox (other browsers limit the argument to 20):
`(0.1).toFixed(55)` returns 
`0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

In the same way, the decimal value `0.2` in binary rounded to a precision of 53 bits and then converted back to decimal is exactly
`0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125`.

If we add the two binary representations of `0.1` and `0.2`, round to 53 bits and then convert back to decimal we get exactly
`0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125`.

So the result of `0.1` + `0.2` in Javascript is not `0.3` but, to 17 decimal places, is `0.30000000000000004`.

In fact, `0.3` can't be exactly represented in binary itself anyway.
It is actually stored as the binary equivalent of the decimal value
`0.29999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125`
which is why in Javascript
`0.2 + 0.1 == 0.3` returns `false`.

---

**Decimal to binary**
A decimal number can only be represented exactly in binary if `2` is the only prime factor of the denominator of the number when it is expressed as a simple fraction in lowest terms.
For example,
`0.1` is `1/10`, and `10` has prime factors `2` and `5`, so no exact representation.
`0.5` is `1/2`,  and the only prime factor of `2` is `2` so it can be represented exactly.